# Automatically reconnecting to wifi

Tags: wifi

Debian 10 without X11.

If I turn my AP off and on again then it shows that Debian reconnects, but Debian does not regain network access -- for example I can't ping anything (although I can ping the AP's IP).

In order to get the network to start working again I have to:

```
# ifdown wlan0
# ifup wlan0
```

Can it be made to resume without manual intervention?

**Edit: `ip a`**

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:9a:20:f3:d8:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:84:0d:f3:7a:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.7/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 2606sec preferred_lft 2606sec
    inet6 fe80::9284:dff:fef3:7a2f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlx00e032800384: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:32:80:03:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:32:80:03:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.31/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e0:32ff:fe80:384/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@mini31:~#
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s10 inet manual

iface wlx00e032800384 inet manual

# Local network: ethernet and hostapd on a second wifi adapter.
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports enp0s10 wlx00e032800384
        address 192.168.1.31
        netmask 255.255.255.0

# This AP often disappears.
# The problem is to get Debian to reconnect to it
# and use it as the default route
# whenever it reappears.
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid RWB
        wpa-psk password

# Future: 4g to use when wlan0 has disappeared.
#auto enp0s4f1u7
#allow-hotplug enp0s4f1u7
#iface enp0s4f1u7 inet dhcp
```

**Edit 2: `ip route`**

```
root@mini31:~# # connected and working
root@mini31:~# ip route
default via 192.168.43.61 dev wlan0
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.31
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.7
root@mini31:~# # now turn off the AP to which wlan0 is connected
root@mini31:~# ip route
default via 192.168.43.61 dev wlan0 linkdown
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.31
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.7 linkdown
root@mini31:~# # now turn the AP back on. This computer soon appears in its list of connected devices.
root@mini31:~# ip route
default via 192.168.43.61 dev wlan0
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.31
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.7
root@mini31:~# ping www.google.com
^C
root@mini31:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.43.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 85ms
pipe 4
root@mini31:~# ifdown wlan0
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/90:84:0d:f3:7a:2f
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/90:84:0d:f3:7a:2f
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPRELEASE of 192.168.43.7 on wlan0 to 192.168.43.87 port 67
root@mini31:~# ifup wlan0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/90:84:0d:f3:7a:2f
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/90:84:0d:f3:7a:2f
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.43.7 from 192.168.43.61
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.43.7 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.43.7 from 192.168.43.61
bound to 192.168.43.7 -- renewal in 1510 seconds.
root@mini31:~# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.211.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr48s13-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=43.6 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 1 received, 66.6667% packet loss, time 37ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 43.577/43.577/43.577/0.000 ms
root@mini31:~#
```

Comment: This was happening to me with a wired connection, apparently there was a mismatch between device's names. What is the output of `ip addr`?

Comment: 1. Is your network managed by NetworkManager?
2. Is your device getting IP? Check ifconfig

Comment: @HeysusEscobar ifconfig is not part of debian 10 tools.

Comment: Bad habits of mine as I work Fedora-based systems . try '''ip add'''

Comment: It appears as if you had two wifi devices: `wlan0` and `wlx00e032800384`.

Comment: Yes. `wlan0` is built-in wifi that I want to use to connect to my AP. `wlx...` is a second adapter on which I have set up an AP using `hostapd`. The idea is to move all my devices from the main AP to the Debian box so that they can use services such as minidlna, samba, netatalk, SQL Server,...

For example at present SQL Server is running on a win7 laptop which always automatically re-connects to the main AP when it becomes available. Similarly, Android phones seamlessly switch from 4G back to wifi. So why can't Debian?

Comment: can you show the output of "ip route" and do a traceroute and ping to google.com and 8.8.8.8 while the problem is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having continued to search for things on this the term *roaming* seemed relevant.

So, I've changed my config as follows and it appears to work.

Here is the new (part of) `/etc/network/interfaces/interfaces`

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
        wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#        wpa-ssid RWB
#        wpa-psk password

allow-hotplug RWB
iface RWB inet dhcp
```

And here is `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="RWB"
    psk="password"
    priority=1
    id_str="RWB"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

Note that the `id_str="RWB"` corresponds to the new pretend interface (it doesn't appear in `ip a`) in `interfaces`.